# How to Count number of occurences of values in all columns

Tags: oracle11g

I am able to find out the Count number of occurrences of values in a single column.
By using

```
select column_name,count(count_name) 
from table_name order by column_name
```

But I want a query for no of occurrences of multiple column values.

Comment: What is the relation between these columns? Also your query is missing  "Group by column_name" to work.

Answer (score 0):

The count function, when used directly on a column, just returns a count of the rows. The sum of the counts over multiple columns is just the amount of rows times the amount of columns. One thing we could do is to return the sum of decodes of the condition over all columns, e.g.:

```
select mytable.*,
DECODE(mytable.column1,"target value",1,0) + DECODE(mytable.column2,"target
value",1,0) as hits from mytable
```

Basically what that does, is for each row, it will check the amount of columns that meet the condition. In this case, that value ('hits') can be 0, 1 or 2 because we are checking the condition over 2 columns.